# Using data attributes for converting date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, gregorian-calendar

i have a javascript function to convert gregorian date to jalali date:

```
year=2019;
month=2;
day=6;

shamsi=gregorian_to_jalali(year,month,day);

document.write(shamsi[0]+ '/' +shamsi[1]+ '/' +shamsi[2]);
```

this result show me: 1397/12/4

For some reason I want to use data attributes in multiple tags like:

```
<date year="2019" month="2" day="6"></date>
```

that each one must return inside

the main function is:

```
function gregorian_to_jalali(gy,gm,gd){
 g_d_m=[0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334];
 if(gy > 1600){
  jy=979;
  gy-=1600;
 }else{
  jy=0;
  gy-=621;
 }
 gy2=(gm > 2)?(gy+1):gy;
 days=(365*gy) +(parseInt((gy2+3)/4)) -(parseInt((gy2+99)/100)) +(parseInt((gy2+399)/400)) -80 +gd +g_d_m[gm-1];
 jy+=33*(parseInt(days/12053)); 
 days%=12053;
 jy+=4*(parseInt(days/1461));
 days%=1461;
 if(days > 365){
  jy+=parseInt((days-1)/365);
  days=(days-1)%365;
 }
 jm=(days < 186)?1+parseInt(days/31):7+parseInt((days-186)/30);
 jd=1+((days < 186)?(days%31):((days-186)%30));
 return [jy,jm,jd];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data-* attribute to store those values.

```html
<div id="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="6"></div>
```

Later, you can read those values in javascript using the [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

```
const dateElement = document.getElementById('date')

const year = dateElement.dataset.year // "2019"
const month = dateElement.dataset.month // "2"
const day = dateElement.dataset.day // "6"
```

Also, if you wish to print the converted date in the same element, just set it with [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```
dateElement.textContent = gregorian_to_jalali(year, month, day).join('/')
```

Comment: The correct answer to this example(2019/2/6) is 1397 12 4 but your code returns 419762 11 7!

Comment: I tried your `gregorian_to_jalali` function and it looks like a problem with type conversion. `data-*` values are always strings, and the `+` operator means different things when used with numbers or strings. In numbers it means addition, so `1 + 2` equals `3`, but with strings it means concatenations, so `"1" + "2"` equals `"12"`. Remember to cast your data to the correct the type. In this case, just add the following at the beginning of your function: `gy = Number(gy); gm = Number(gm); gd = Number(gd);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a single attribute in JSON format, then you can parse the JSON to get the values:

```js
// Stub for dev
function gregorian_to_jalali(gy, gm, gd){
  console.log(`From gregorian_to_jalali: ${gy}, ${gm}, ${gd}`);
}

// Get value from element and parse
function getValue(element) {
  let {year, month, day} = JSON.parse(element.dataset.value);
  return [year, month, day];
}

// Get values
console.log(getValue(document.querySelector('date')));

// Use in a function
gregorian_to_jalali(...getValue(document.querySelector('date')));
```

```html
<date data-value='{"year":"2019","month":"2","day":"6"}'></date>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work like a charm!

```
const year = Number(dateElement.dataset.year) // "2019"
const month = Number(dateElement.dataset.month) // "2"
const day = Number(dateElement.dataset.day) // "6"
```

i want to use it for multiple tags like:

```
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="3" data-day="6"></div>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="4" data-day="7"></div>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="5" data-day="8"></div>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="6" data-day="9"></div>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="7" data-day="10"></div>
```

i know `document.getElementById()` only supports one name at a time and only returns a single node not an array of nodes. but also its not working on `getElementsByClassName` or TagName